# BroadcastReceiver with Respont

Tags: java, android

I have an on click listener which should cause a function call in another class to wait for a return value so that the return can be processed afterwards.

I had different approaches. (In this order.)

- Interface: However, I cannot initialize this in the Onglick listener.
- BroadcastReceiver: As far as I understood this is not the right way because a BroadcastReceiver only provides a function call but does not return a value.

Possibly have this problem several beginners. Can someone help me in this regard?

I have now supplemented the question with a picture.
I need everything that is black works and has been tested so I only need the remote function call.

I would like to add a static aufrunf is not possible because the app in the background constantly scans the environment and crap. With the connected device is then only provided via services of several functionalities.

[image]

Comment: Hi @rene, do you want to make an asynchronous call? Is your other class an activity or something like a ViewModel? And does "interface" mean a callback?

Comment: in my case it is not posible. Because it is a Onglick listener in a ListPreverence. So i will implement a BroadcastReceiver or others you can make an execute in an another class and wait for return. And after getting the return, the rest of the code can be processed.

Comment: So, just a normal method call? Please post some code of what you have tried (i.e. preferences listener, the class you want to call), it might help clarify your question

Comment: @Sergei Kozelko This only works if you have a static methoden call. The black function on the left side come from an Clas who wos initialisate in the MainActivity,